# How to notifi when new activity is started?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am developing one application related to ActivityManager. In that I am getting a list of applications running in the system using the fallowing code.

```
ActivityManger.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE)

List<RunningTaskInfo> a=am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

PackageManager pack=this.getPackageManager(); 

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){

    String packageName = a.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();
    String appName= (String) pack.getApplicationLabel(pack.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Drawable d=pack.getApplicationIcon(packageName);

  Log.v("details"," "+packageName+" && "+appName);    

    }
```

By using the above i am getting list of activities are running.ok fine

But my intenction is how to notify when new activity is stared.

Is there any observers in activity manager.

If any one has idea,please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity's Life cycle onStart(), onCreate(), onRemuse(), OnDestroy();**

At the Calling of Activity or to start Intent:

put your notify code in `OnStart()`

for notification: https://web.archive.org/web/20210127142125/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/03/notification-in-android.html

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well,what you can do is ,simply run this code in a service inside a thread.
Trigger this code every minute. And then using NotificationManager, you can notify user in the notification bar, incase if any new app is launched.